# Complex integral on a simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I try to translate a statement that I've read in a translated „Introduction to Complex Analysis” book...

Let me define $f$ as a continuous complex valued function on a set $D\subset\mathbb{C}$, where $g'=f$ (so the complex derivative of $g$ is $f$). If $\Gamma\subset D$, then

$$\int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=g\left(\gamma\left(b\right)\right)-g\left(\gamma\left(a\right)\right),$$

where $\gamma$ is a representation of $\Gamma$. Specially, if $\Gamma$ is a simple closed curve, then

$$\int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=0.$$

The proof was the following:

$$\int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz\dot{=}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\gamma'\left(t\right)dt=\int_{a}^{b}g'\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\gamma'\left(t\right)dt=\int_{a}^{b}\left(g\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\right)'dt=g\left(\gamma\left(b\right)\right)-g\left(\gamma\left(a\right)\right),$$

where (I guess) we used the definition of complex integral, the chain rule and as a last step the Newton-Leibniz formula. In this case if $\Gamma$ is a closed curve, then $\gamma\left(a\right)=\gamma\left(b\right)$, so

$$\int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=g\left(\gamma\left(b\right)\right)-g\left(\gamma\left(a\right)\right)=g\left(\gamma\left(b\right)\right)-g\left(\gamma\left(b\right)\right)=0.$$

However, the „specially” part feels strange to me. I would say the following counter example, which is definitely not a counter example, but I dont know what I miss from the statement...

If $\Gamma\dot{=}C\left(0,1\right)$ is the complex unit circle, then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi it}}2\pi ie^{2\pi it}dt=2\pi i\neq0.$$

So why isn't it a counter example? Is the proof not correct at some point? $C\left(0,1\right)$ is a simple closed curve, $f$ is continuous on e.g. $D\dot{=}\left\{ z:z\in\mathbb{C},\frac{1}{2}<\left|z\right|<\frac{3}{2}\right\}$, and $\Gamma\subset D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f:z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$ does not have a primitive $g$ on any circular neighbourhood. You might be thinking that $g=\log $ works, but it doesn't, because you will always run into the following problem: let's say, we choose the argument of a complex number to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, choosing $\log(-1)=\pi i$. As $z\to-1$ from above the real axis, $\log z\to\pi i$, but as $z\to-1$ from below we have $\log z\to-\pi i$. So $g$ isn't even *continuous*, never mind differentiable.

Comment: This perfectly makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: ...and an other one last exapmle...for $\int_{C\left(0,1\right)}Im(z)dz$ I get $-\pi$...which is not $0$ ... again: what is missing from the statement above? Or my calculation is wrong?

Comment: $\int_{C\left(0,1\right)}Im(z)dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}Im\left(e^{it}\right)ie^{it}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}Im\left(\cos t+i\sin t\right)ie^{it}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin t\cdot ie^{it}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}ie^{it}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2it}-e^{0}dt=-\pi$

Comment: @KapesMate That looks fine to me. Exactly the same thing is missing: $z\mapsto\Im z$ has no holomorphic primitive. In fact, it *nowhere* has a holomorphic primitive, as that would imply it itself is holomorphic, but $z\mapsto\Im z$ isn’t differentiable. Any purely real or purely imaginary function is not differentiable

Comment: You must be right again...because the Cauchy-Riemann equations don't hold...thank you again...

Comment: @KapesMate No worries! You’re welcome